# Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode9, photoeditorsdk

I am trying to compile my code in Xcode 9 which is written in swift. I am using pod -> PhotoEditorSDK and it continiuosly shows me this error.

> Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2: /Users/iAakash/Downloads/pesdk-ios-examples-master/Examples/SwiftExample/Pods/PhotoEditorSDK/pesdk-ios-build-7.3.0/PhotoEditorSDK.framework/Modules/PhotoEditorSDK.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule

I have tried the following:

1. Deleted the derived data
2. Cleaned the project folder and restarted Xcode 9
3. Tried forcing the swift version ['SWIFT VERSION'] to 3.2

All this have been of no use.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: I can't see your error.

Comment: Its a closed source framework. You'll need to ask the developers who make it what their support is for Swift 3.2/Xcode9.

Comment: After cleaning the project, try updating the Pod. i.e. `pod install or pod update` will fix the issue. Also, I agree with Warren.

Comment: @WarrenBurton Thats what I have done for the moment.

Comment: @Rahul Tried that too. Didn't quite help. I guess I just have to wait.

Comment: @AakashDave were u successful in getting the support for PhotoEditorSDK  Swift 3.2, Xcode 9 ? Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Bean oh! They actually mailed me saying mentioning the steps I had to take. I just didn’t test it out again then. It’s a solid Library though!

Comment: Thanks man !! I have also emailed them, let see what they reply. Also can you please forward me the email so I can have a look at the steps. 
Email id : misra.shivang@gmail.com.  Thank you :)

Comment: Any help would be appreciated @AakashDave, thank you

Comment: @Mr.Bean mailed you. Cheers :)

Comment: thanks man @AakashDave. :)